# Text editable con value predeterminado

Tags: reactjs

Tengo un formulario en donde carga un texto que ya viene predeterminado pero quiero que sea editable. He usado la propiedad value pero no me permite escribir, aqui mi codigo

```html
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const data = [
    {
      id: 23,
      puntoControl:
        "¿Se encuentran disponibles todos los registros, incluidos los relativos a la inocuidad alimentaria, y se conservan durante un período mínimo de 2 años, excepto cuando se requiera un plazo mayor en puntos de control específicos? ",
      justificacion:
        "Si, si cumple, el productor presenta registros actualizados durante un periodo de:"
    }
  ];

  const [registro, setRegistro] = useState({
    opcion: "",
    justificacion: ""
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setRegistro((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value
    }));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.map((item) => (
        <>
          <div className="col-12">
            <div className="text-primary">Opción:</div>
            <select
              name="opcion"
              className="form-control"
              onChange={handleChange}
              required
            >
              <option value={0}> - Seleccione - </option>
              <option value={"SI"}>SI</option>
              <option value={"NO"}>NO</option>
              <option value={"NA"}>N/A</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div className="col-12">
            <textarea
              className="textos form-control"
              rows="3"
              name="justificacion"
              value={item.justificacion}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </div>
        </>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/update-text-value-py0k9?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Controlled Components ReactJS

Se debe controlar el `textarea` con react, ya casi esta controlado solo falta mapear la propiedad `name`:

```
<textarea
    className="textos form-control"
    rows="3"
    name={item.justificacion}
    value={item.justificacion}
    onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

Ahora bien, se debe usar un estado para inyectar sus valores a los elementos, junto con los nombres de las propiedades del mismo:

```
const [registro, setRegistro] = useState(data);
```

También, el set que se usa para el cambio de estado envía un objeto:

```
//computed prop [name]:value
setRegistro((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value
}));
```

Se debe enviar un array:

```
//computed prop [name]:value
setRegistro((prevState) => [{
  ...prevState,
  [name]:value
}]);
```

---

Con estos cambios ya se podrá observar el cambio del valor para el estado `justificacion`:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const data = [
    {
      id: 23,
      puntoControl:
        "¿Se encuentran disponibles todos los registros, incluidos los relativos a la inocuidad alimentaria, y se conservan durante un período mínimo de 2 años, excepto cuando se requiera un plazo mayor en puntos de control específicos? ",
      justificacion:
        "Si, si cumple, el productor presenta registros actualizados durante un periodo de:"
    }
  ];
  const [registro, setRegistro] = useState(data);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setRegistro((prevState) => [{
      ...prevState,
      [name]:value
    }]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {registro.map((item) => (
        <>
          <div className="col-12">
            <div className="text-primary">Opción:</div>
            <select
              name={item.id}
              className="form-control"
              onChange={handleChange}
              required
            >
              <option value="0"> - Seleccione - </option>
              <option value="SI">SI</option>
              <option value="NO">NO</option>
              <option value="NA">N/A</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div className="col-12">
            <textarea
              className="textos form-control"
              rows="3"
              name={item.justificacion}
              value={item.justificacion}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </div>
        </>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Ya solo hay que revisar bien el estado `registro`, sobre todo para el `select`, pues en el demo solo hice el mapeo de `id` para el `select`, pero sus `options` son datos duros, no estoy seguro ahí.

[ES2015 Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015)

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

Comment: Lo he modificado como indicas, pero hay un problema. Para el ejemplo declaré los datos de data ahí mismo pero esos datos vienen de una api, al hacer las modificaciones ahora ya no muestran nada al usuario. En el link que dice demo viene mi codigo.

Comment: Bien, pues con la respuesta que te compartí puedes mantener el cambio en el `textarea` durante el re-render (cuando el usuario modifica el text); di un vistazo al demo y si funciona, ¿A que te refieres con que no muestra nada al cliente? Saludos